# line visible while creating css chat bubble

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the css chat bubble while creating it I can see one line running through the triangle in my chat bubble as below picture [image]

The same works without any issue on chrome browser but on old xulrunner browser this  gives a line.

```css
.talk-bubble {
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.triangle.left-top:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -20px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.right-top:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 32px solid;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="talk-bubble triangle left-top">
  <p>Left flush at the top.</p>
</div>
<div class="talk-bubble triangle right-top">
  <p>Right flush at the top.</p>
</div>
```

Any clue on what's going wrong will be helpful.

Comment: Try `z-index: -1;` for the corners

Answer (score 0):

as @bhuvan said just add negative z-index

```css
.talk-bubble {
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.triangle.left-top:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -20px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
z-index:-1;
}

.triangle.right-top:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 32px solid;
z-index:-1;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="talk-bubble triangle left-top">
  <p>Left flush at the top.</p>
</div>
<div class="talk-bubble triangle right-top">
  <p>Right flush at the top.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Though it's better but Still the downside edges have a line .Thanks by the way

Comment: try removing border